# Can I make a build without the device

Tags: iphone

I am beginner in iPhone.

I dont' have iPhone but I have all developer id and certificate. Is this possible to make the build without the iPhone device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** use the iPhone/iPad simulator to test against, but I would advise against solely testing against it. You should always test against a real device before releasing it into the wild

Comment: But I dont have a iPhone right now. Its require to send the build to other to test it. So in this case it simulator and deveper id is enough to make the build

Comment: okay. Can you help me how to make the build that run on the device. Please give any link to me

Comment: You can find the answer to almost any iOS question on the very detailed iOS Developer Library: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please I need to make build compatible with all iphone version. What is required for this in the code or any settings

Comment: That's too general a question. You need to read the documentation as per the link above.

Comment: can you please specific link to me

Comment: I doubt it'll get accepted to the store. There is a huge amount of things that can/will go wrong on a real device, compared to the simulator.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer I am just using the webview, sqllite, making call only. Is this make any different in simulator or real device

Comment: Did you test for limited network availability? Low memory warnings? Performance? It's not required but so much easier with a real device.